# Python. Adding custom methods to existing site-packages

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl with python 2.7 to manipulate some workbooks. I've implemented my own methods for class Worksheet except they're not being found when I try to access them. I''m on windows and I've adding the following code to site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py. Source code [here](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/5961d9dc9e51d70824b40517d52103cb4fd7c673/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).

```
class Worksheet(_WorkbookChild):
"""
Library defined methods here.
"""

    #My Method.
    def hello_world(self):
       print "Hello from worksheet."
```

When I open up a workbook and try and call my function it raises an error for 'no attribute' even though it's been defined (properly?) under the scope of the class Worksheet.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('helloworld.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_active_sheet()

sheet.hello_world()
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'hello_world'
```

Do I need to do anything differently to update the existing library? I've deleted the .pyc, recompiled and am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who runs into this problem. The library was using 4 spaces for each indent while I was using a regular tab. The variation in indents caused the method to not be defined even though it appeared to be.

Comment: Mixing tabs and spaces will raise an exception if you use Python 3. The recommendation is **always** use spaces and configure your editor accordingly.